# How to handle download, share and delete icon through Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: css, selenium-webdriver, xpath

1.How to handle download(excel icon), share and delete icon through Selenium webdriver using java.

2.How to handle different locations hirerarchy in selenium webdriver usign java.

eg:  Region(expand country displays)
        country(expands list of state displays)
            State(expands list of county displays and further so on)

Comment: Welcome to SO,Please update the post with html of the elements,code that you tried and any error messages.

Comment: #noanim-tab-example-pane-1 > div > div > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(5) > div > span:nth-child(1) > svg > path   - This is path of download icon

Comment: 1. an icon is just another WebElement 2. via xpaths or via parent WebElement's child WebElements